# Formula for Validation Rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I'm trying to create a formula for a validation rule where if a checkbox is marked for "Field A" then an email address must be entered in for "Field B". What would a formula like this look like? Would I use the IF function? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shoule [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far. Even if it doesn't work or it gives you an error, showing us _something_ helps people give you better answers. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof, like validation rules) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started. There is a specific module on [Formlas and Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write formula as

> FieldA__c && ISBLANK( FieldB )

Comment: Thank you that worked! What if I also wanted to auto populate today's date in another field say Field C.

Comment: You can add default value of the field as TODAY().I hope this will work for you !!

Comment: Thank you, Karan. So I have the formula as follows below:

FieldA  && ISBLANK(  FieldB  )  && 
(FieldC = TODAY())

The syntax says there are no errors but when I attempt to put things in motion, the date field will not update automatically.